# Закрытие книги после импорта

Tags: excel, vba, sas

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу закрыть открытую книгу после копирования с нее данных. После выполнения всех операций использую:

`openWb.Close False`

И все работает по плану, но как только выбираю книгу, в которой по умолчанию выделены все листы, метод `close` не хочет работать.
Думал изменить выделения в открываемой книге действием:

`openWb.Sheets(2).select`

И любыми другими комбинациями `select` и `active`, но выводит ошибку.

Как это можно решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем листы выделять? Копировать можно без активации

Comment: Да и активация листа не должна мешать... Покажите код

Answer (score 1):

Суть проблемы была в специфике форматa книги excel, SAS генерировал файл в несовсем новой версии и видимо поэтому были проблемы с закрытием.